# Covariant derivative and tensor symmetries

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

Suppose we have a tensor field $T^{ab}$ such that $T^{ab} = T^{ba}$ everywhere. Then from the definition of the Riemannian covariant derivative in terms of a map between tensors, why must we then have $(\nabla_c T)^{ab} = (\nabla_c T)^{ba}$?

Comment: That's not a physics question.

Comment: Neither is [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118547/covariant-derivative-of-a-covariant-tensor-wrt-superscript?rq=1), [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/arbitrary-tensor-covariant-derivative?rq=1) or [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104774/covariant-derivative-as-a-tensor?rq=1).

Comment: One the one hand, if we try to draw boundaries between where physics ends and math begins this is an impossible task.  On the other hand, I think that @ACuriousMind is correct that you'd be more likely to get a good answer by posting to the Mathematics community on StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely the result follows rather quickly from one of the questions you linked.  Use

$$\nabla_{c} T^{ab} = \partial_{c}T^{ab}+ \Gamma^a{}_{cd} T^{db} + \Gamma^b {}_{dc}T^{ad}.$$

From this we can get $$\nabla_{c} T^{ba} = \partial_{c}T^{ba}+ \Gamma^b{}_{cd} T^{da} + \Gamma^a {}_{dc}T^{bd}.$$

Then subtract to get

$\begin{array}\nabla_{c} T^{ab}-\nabla_{c} T^{ba} &=& \partial_{c}T^{ab}+ \Gamma^a{}_{cd} T^{db} + \Gamma^b {}_{dc}T^{ad} -\partial_{c}T^{ba}- \Gamma^b{}_{cd} T^{da} - \Gamma^a {}_{dc}T^{bd} \\
 &=&\partial_{c}(T^{ab}-T^{ba})+ \Gamma^a{}_{cd} T^{db} - \Gamma^a {}_{dc}T^{bd} + \Gamma^b {}_{dc}T^{ad} - \Gamma^b{}_{cd} T^{da}\\
 &=&\partial_{c}(T^{ab}-T^{ba})+ (\Gamma^a{}_{cd}  - \Gamma^a {}_{dc})T^{bd} + (\Gamma^b {}_{dc}- \Gamma^b{}_{cd}) T^{da} \\
 &=&\partial_{c}(T^{ab}-T^{ba})+ 0T^{bd} + 0 T^{da} \\ 
&=&\partial_{c}(T^{ab}-T^{ba}) =0.  \end{array}$

Now the first line is from the linked posts, the second from linearity of differentiation, the third is from point wise symmetry of $T$ and the next is from the connection being torsion free (symmetry of Christoffel symbols) and the final is from neighborhood wise symmetry of T

Comment: A concise mathematical explanation. Me likes.